# getdate call for another way in same scope

Tags: php

using getdate function assign today to the today.but why today year assign to year.its return date also know ?

```
    $today = getdate();
    $year=$today['year'];
    $mounth=$today['mon'];
```

in here i'm unclear about why today is call for the year

Comment: your question doesn't make any sense, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: i ask about why $year=$today['year']; WHY here $today use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because when you assign to `$today` the function `getdate()`, `$today` will be an array of values

So year is also assigned in that array.

```
Array
(
    [seconds] => 1
    [minutes] => 15
    [hours] => 11
    [mday] => 13
    [wday] => 3
    [mon] => 6
    [year] => 2012
    [yday] => 164
    [weekday] => Wednesday
    [month] => June
    [0] => 1339575301
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to abstract your question for me. I will try my best to understand it.

The variable $today is assigned by you. You can have any meaning for that. But what is returned from getdate() funciton is a full set of date for the current time.

check the explaination given in PHP manual for the funciton

> Returns an associative array containing the date information of  the timestamp, or the current local time if no timestamp is given.

Check the complete manual and usage here.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php

It might help you understand the function well.